# Is checkbox validation with validate.js library broken?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need to add client-side form validation to an HTML5 form. I don't want to hack my own solution and I'm not using Angular.

Since I'm using HTML5, the `pattern` and `required` attributes combined cover basic validation.

However, where custom validation is needed, for example, requiring a specific combination of checkboxes are ticked - I need something more.

A quick web search took me to [The 10 Best JavaScript Libraries for Form Validation and Formatting](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/the-ten-best-javascript-libraries-for-form-validation-and-formatting/#sthash.n1DBRais.dpuf).

I tested out [Validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) and hit a problem when validating checkboxes.  [Validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) binds to specific form elements by name, e.g.

```
var validator = new FormValidator('example_form', [{
    name: 'req',
    rules: 'required'
});
```

The corresponding HTML form:

```
<form name="example_form">
<input name="req" />
</form>
```

I decided to apply this to a group of checkboxes AND implement my own custom rule ([documented on Validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/)):

```
 <form name="example_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="a">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="b">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="c">
</form>
```

Firstly, the Validator configuration object adding my custom rule:

```
var validator = new FormValidator('example_form', [{
    name: 'test',
    rules: 'callback_my_rule'
});
```

...notice the `required` rule (provided out-of-the-box) is gone, and has been replaced by my own rule `callback_my_rule`. Next I defined `my_rule` (as per the documentation, the `callback_` prefix is dropped):

```
validator.registerCallback('my_rule', function(value) {
    var atLeastOne = ($('[name="test"]:checked').length > 0);
    return atLeastOne;
});
```

A return value of `False` means validation failed, whereas `True` is valid.

The problem is, if no checkboxes are ticked, my custom validation function, `my_rule`, is never called.  Only when I tick a checkbox is the function called. It seems a unintuitive to only call custom validation functions when a checkbox is ticked.

The [Validate.js documentation](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) provides an example form with a checkbox, however, the checkbox validation function is omitted from the sample code: [image]

However, the example form does validate the checkbox, digging around the source of [Validate.js documentation](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/), I see the checkbox uses the out-of-the-box `required` rule: [image]

Questions

- Has anyone got Validate.js working with checkboxes and custom
  validation functions?
- Is there a better library for custom form
  validation?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @brso05 - No errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tested [Jquery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and works like a charm with checkbox!

**DEMO LINK** http://jsfiddle.net/K6Wvk/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#formid').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                'inputname': {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                'inputname': {
                    required: "You must check at least 1 box",
                    maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: This JQuery plugin does what I need and appears to be better supported  (community and documentation. I switched to it, so am accepting this answer.